# string search with user defined mismatch perl

Tags: perl, fuzzy-search

I am trying to search a substring in a string with certain mismatch (mismatch allowed is taken from user). I came across String::Approx but I cant seem to understand how it work and your input is appreciated.

```
use String::Approx 'aindex';
$a="Aperlisaparlhardobjectproduced...";
$b="paal";
print aindex($b, ["I0", "D0", "S1"], $a);
```

When I search with 1 substitution, it works fine (I0 and D0 because I want to search for same length match) and gives output as 8. When I search with S2 or S3 it still gives 8 instead of position 1 (should have matched perl). Is it intended result?

Thank you!

Comment: Strange - it returns `1` with just `["2"]`, but not `["S2"]`.  Seems like a bug?

Comment: Thank you. checked with ["2"] works. As you mentioned, this could be a bug.